# Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined in Kendo ListView

Tags: javascript, listview, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I get this error

> Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

when I load my grid. 
What I assume it happens is that the TemplateId is not recognized.
My list view

```
 @(Html.Kendo().ListView<DocsViewModel>()
     .Name("listView")
            .TagName("div")
            .ClientTemplateId("DocumentList")
     )
```

And the column that keeps what I want to have in my listView

```
  columns.Bound(od => od.DocumentList).Width(150).ClientTemplate("#=generateTemplate(DocumentList)#");
```

And this is my JavaScript Function

```
 function generateTemplate(DocumentList) {

        var template = "<ul>";
        if (DocumentList == null || DocumentList == undefined) {

            template = template + "<li> </li>";
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < DocumentList .length; i++) {
                var url = '@Url.Action("DownloadDocument", "Controller")?filename=' + DocumentList [i];
                template = template + "<a href='" + url + "'>" + DocumentList [i] + "</a> ";
            }
        }
        return template + "</ul>";
    }
```

How can I fix this error? I tried to give the listView as a TemplateId the DocumentList, but is undefined. Do I need to send somehow DocumentList from the `generatateTemplate` function to this listView?

Comment: Can't see you adding <li> elements while looping!?

Comment: That is not really the problem